# How to run client side tests with JHipster v5.8.2 on Windows?

Tags: jhipster

I am using JHipster v5.8.2 on Windows operating system and I am trying to run Jest client side tests by running the command:

```
npm test
```

But I get an error that says:

```
No tests found, exiting with code 1
Run with `--passWithNoTests` to exit with code 0
In C:\IdeaProjects\pomzen
  274 files checked.
  testMatch: 
C:/IdeaProjects/pomzen/src/test/javascript/spec/**\+(*.)+(spec.ts) - 0 
matches
  testPathIgnorePatterns: \\node_modules\\ - 274 matches
  testRegex:  - 0 matches
Pattern:  - 0 matches
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Can you please enter it in JHipster's bug tracker with steps to reproduce? https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues

Comment: I get this error on 5.8.2 when packaging a gateway for docker './mvnw package -Pprod verify jib:dockerBuild', but not when running the default build ./mvnw, Jakub's work-around prevents the failure.

Answer (score 1):

I recently also had this problem. I used workaround from here:
https://github.com/DorianGrey/ng-webpack-template/pull/22/commits/fe95926607ed8bd01476c7d04b5b930a965ad282

Fix:

1. Open **jest.conf.js** file
2. Replace

```js
testMatch: ['<rootDir>/src/test/javascript/spec/**/+(*.)+(spec.ts)']
```

with

```js
testMatch: ['**/*.spec.ts']
```